How to use async completable future
I am trying to run two processes (both making external REST calls) in parallel such that the the results of 1st process will be used based on values after 2nd process completes otherwise discarded. While running in debug the following code, it seems like a blocking call. How do I fix this?
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<String> asyncFuture1 = null;
        CompletableFuture<String> asyncFuture2 = null;

        try {
            asyncFuture1 = future1("Future 1");
            asyncFuture2 = future2("Future 2");

            CompletableFuture<String> message1 = asyncFuture1.thenApplyAsync(s -> s);
            CompletableFuture<String> message2 = asyncFuture2.thenApplyAsync(s -> s);

            System.out.println(message1.get());
            System.out.println(message2.get());


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> future1(String message) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println("In Future 1" + message);
                        return message;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<String> future2(String message) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println("In Future 2" + message);
                        return message;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}



CompletableFuture.get() is a blocking call. What did you expect to happen?

I was expecting "Infuture 1" in console after line "...asyncFuture1.thenApplyAsync..."

I need both the calls to start in parallel.

There is nothing slow in your code, so everything happens almost instantaneously. By the time thenApplyAsync() is invoked, it’s possible that the futures have already completed. Maybe add some sleep before return message to see the effects.

Probably not able to see it in IDE. What you are saying is that the workers have already started when I do future1(..), future2(..)?

I dont see anywhere where "the results of 1st process will be used based on values after 2nd process completes otherwise discarded". It just looks like you are running 2 completable futures and getting the messages

The asynchronous operation starts when supplyAsync is called. That’s what “supplyAsync” means, supply a value asynchronously. It’s even possible that the operation already finished when your main thread returns from future1. The thenApplyAsync(s -> s) serves no recognizable purpose.

Thank you! If you can put this as an answer, I can put it as resolved. Thanks again!
